# How to define a struct of several strings in it?

Tags: c

I want to define a struct in a C header file, which contains several strings.
For example, 3 files are listed below and struct fileList is defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILE1 "/data/file1"
#define FILE2 "/data/file2"
#define FILE3 "/data/file3"

typedef struct fileList{
    FILE1;
    FILE2;
    FILE3;
}fileList;

int main()
{
    fileList fl;
    printf("Hello world! %s\n", fl.FILE1);

}
```

But when I run it, I got bellow errors.
Why? And do you have better solution?
Thanks!

```
gcc test.c 
test.c:3:15: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before string constant
 #define FILE1 "/data/file1"
               ^
test.c:8:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘FILE1’
     FILE1;
     ^
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:3:15: error: expected identifier before string constant
 #define FILE1 "/data/file1"
               ^
test.c:16:36: note: in expansion of macro ‘FILE1’
     printf("Hello world! %s\n", fl.FILE1);
```

Comment: Structs have fields which are *variables*. You are trying to put *values* there. Values can be given to the fields at the initialization stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `#define` macros as something that get searched and replaced. If you replace the macros with their definitions you get:

```
typedef struct fileList{
    "/data/file1";
    "/data/file2";
    "/data/file3";
}fileList;
```

and

```
printf("Hello world! %s\n", fl."/data/file1");
```

Those snippets are clearly not syntactically valid.

---

It looks like you're trying to create a struct with three string fields. One way to do that might be:

```
typedef struct fileList {
    const char *file1;
    const char *file2;
    const char *file3;
} fileList;
```

Then if you want to create an instance of that struct and set the *values* of those string fields to the string literals you listed, you could write:

```
int main() {
    fileList fl;
    fl.file1 = "/data/file1";
    fl.file2 = "/data/file2";
    fl.file3 = "/data/file3";
    printf("Hello world! %s\n", fl.file1);
}
```

No need for preprocessor macros at all.

Comment: ...or simply `fileList fl= {"/data/file1", "/data/file2", "/data/file3"};`.

Comment: `file1`, `file2`, and `file3` should probably be arrays, not pointers, yes?  since AFAIK, if you give a `char` pointer a string literal, then the string will stay a literal and won't be manipulable.

Comment: Perhaps, yes. I didn't want to get into the ins and outs of string handling. It's a complicated subject that's tackled in great depth in many other places.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
typedef struct fileList{
    FILE1;
    FILE2;
    FILE3;
}fileList;
```

this does not result in a valid data item.  Suggest:

```
struct fileList{
    char *FILE1;
    char *FILE2;
    char *FILE3;
};
typedef struct fileList  fileList;
```